# Drawing with subplot command in matlab but different function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I use a matlab function. This fuction is using pieces of the same image. But at the end i dont combine this pieces. I can show only different figures. How can i rejoin this image? (i had seen 'ImageAssemble' command used by Mathematica,maybe matlab has function like that.)If there is no one function, i think this peaces can be showed under subplot command but problem is i have to open subplot in function and when i invoked function everytime, different subplot is opening. I want to only one subplot open. For example i have a function like below

```
function[] =seperate(I,n,m)
I1=I(1:m/2,1:n/2);
I2=I(1:m/2,n/2+1:n);
I3=I(m/2+1:m,1:n/2);
I4=I(m/2+1:m,n/2+1:n);
subplot(2,4,1)   %for eight image
imshow(I1);
subplot(2,4,2)
imshow(I2);
subplot(2,4,3)
imshow(I3);
subplot(2,4,4)
imshow(I4);
end
```

there is a actual program

```
img=imread('any_image.jpg');
gray=rgb2gray(img);
[n,m] = size(gray);
seperate(gray,n,m);
img_2=imread('any_image_2');
gray_2=rgb2gray(img_2);
[n1,m1]=size(gray_2)
seperate(gray_2,n1,m1);
```

As you can see this 'seperate' function is seperating 4 equal peaces an image. When you used this function in two different image, you have two different subplot. I want one subplot. For example first image peaces should be placed 'subplot(2,4,1),subplot(2,4,2),subplot(2,4,3),subplot(2,4,4)' and second image peaces should be placed 'subplot(2,4,5),subplot(2,4,6),subplot(2,4,7),subplot(2,4,8)' . How can I do this?
 Also  Can I rejoin these peaces and i can create a new image as an one peace that consists of 8 peaces of first two peaces? Thank you for help.

Comment: Just pass both images to `separate` and add more `subplot` calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is awfully stated and there are errors in your initial code. However, since code was provided I ran it and managed to understand the problem:

You are calling a function (which has some graphic output) twice, but you want the graphics to be output in the same **`figure`** (*you use the word `subplot` way too much, and sometimes not appropriately*).

The way to make sure a function will always plot in the same figure is:

- attach an *identifier* to the target figure (I used the `tag`
  property of the figure, but you could use other properties (`Name`)
  as long as you can assign a *unique* identifier).
- when the function has to do the graphic output, it first search if
  the target figure exist. You can use the function [`findobj`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) for that. If `yes` it direct output to it, if `no` it
  creates a new one.

Below is a rewrite of your function `seperate.m`:

```
function seperate(I,subset)

    % default subset = 1
    if nargin < 2 ; subset=1 ; end

    % first find if the target figure already exist
    hfig = findobj(0,'Type','figure','Tag','SeparatingFigure') ;
    if isempty(hfig)
        figure('Tag','SeparatingFigure') ; % create a new one
    else
        figure(hfig) ; % just make the existing figure active
    end

    % now split the image in 4 pieces
    [m,n] = size(I);
    Isplit{1} = I(1:m/2,1:n/2) ;
    Isplit{2} = I(1:m/2,n/2+1:n);
    Isplit{3} = I(m/2+1:m,1:n/2);
    Isplit{4} = I(m/2+1:m,n/2+1:n);

    % now display to the proper set of subplots
    % "subpos" store the index of the 4 subplot to use for 1 subset
    subpos = [1 2 5 6 ; ... %subset "1" will plot in subplot [1 2 5 6]
              3 4 7 8] ;    %subset "2" will plot in subplot [3 4 7 8]
    for k=1:4
        subplot(2,4,subpos(subset,k))   
        imshow(Isplit{k});
    end
end
```

I took the liberty to refactor partially the code in order to be able to use loops (instead of a long list of almost repeated statements).

When you use the function, the `subset` parameter takes value `1` or `2` to indicate on which subplots the 4 parts will be plotted. You can use it that way:

```
img1=imread('coins.png');
seperate(img1,1);

img2=imread('peppers.png');
seperate(img2,2);
```

[image: separated1]

And any new image you throw at it will simply replace the old one (still in the same figure):

```
% replace the first subset with another image
img3=imread('football.jpg');
seperate(img3,1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what i need. Also can we make one peace these seperate peaces end of the process?

Comment: well, you already split the images manually, you can just re-attach the pieces together. Something like `Ifull = [ Isplit{1} , Isplit{2} ; Isplit{3} , Isplit{4} ]`